# Issue with Custom URL reverting to standard Salesforce domain URL

Tags: force.com-sites

I have a site with a custom url set up so that if `http://mycustomdomain.com` is entered into the browser then the CNAME record for that domain redirects to the underlying Salesforce domain for my site `http://mysalesforcedomain.force.com/mysite`.

Some of the links on a page in my site call a JavaScript function that does either of the following:

```
 window.location.href = "http://" + window.location.host + "/mysite/mypage?param="+param
```

or

```
 window.open(http://" + window.location.host + "/mysite/mypage?param=param", "_blank");
```

I notice that when the `window.location.href` is set then when the page changes the url in the browser is simply `http://mycustomdomain.com` without any parameter information. But when I use the `window.open()` function to open a new tab in the browser, the url set in that new tab is `http://mysalesforcedomain.force.com/mysite?param=value`.

I find it odd that the url would remain the custom domain with one method,  but would revert to the Salesforce domain name in the other.

Is there a reason this is happening, or any way to prevent it without hard-coding the custom domain name?

I'd also be interested to know why, when the custom domain name, is showing, there are no parameters showing.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you seeing this issue when you are authenticated or unauthenticated?

Comment: Hi Jesse. We are using our own authentication methods.

Comment: So you Salesforce site is unauthenticated ?  Did you add the VF page + controller to the profile of the Site public user ?  Is it a standard or custom object controller ?

Comment: do you have a live example you could post?

Comment: or could you just use a relative URL?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you consider:

- [Apex Developer Guide: Rewrite URLs for Salesforce Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm)

Comment: Seems like the list of `Restricted Strings` may be a roadblock for OP.